# How to detect page has been rendered when using PDF.js

Tags: pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to render the pdf content in web browser. It works perfect in desktop browser but I noticed inconsistent behavior in iPad. In iPad, some time pdf.js render blank/white canvas.

I tried to get the event when the page has finished its rendering. Below is the lines of code:

```
var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
renderTask.then(function () {
  console.log('Page rendered');
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log('Error :: ' + error);
});
```

It works fine when pdf is rendered and canvas has pdf content. But it does not called when canvas comes with blank/white screen.

Is there any way to get rid of this white/blank screen for iPad using pdf.js.

Comment: See the FAQ: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support

Comment: is ipad's version of safari different from desktop? [in the past](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5341) there was an issue with old safari